# What are the side effects of marking a derived implementation noexcept while the interface is not

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, noexcept

We have a class which implements IUnknown (or any interface which we don't own).  We started marking most/all of our methods with noexcept for any potential optimization since we don't throw any exceptions anyway; although some of the libraries we depend on may.  The question was raised whether or not QueryInterface/AddRef/Release should be marked noexcept since the interface isn't.

Are there any side effects or gotchas when only some of the derived classes are marked noexcept?

Comment: Beware that `noexcept` isn't free. It's not a great idea to throw it on all the functions. The cost is that you can't really remove it once you've put it on. Other `noexcept` code might rely on your function's `noexcept` so for backwards compatibility you are stuck with. That means you can't ever change the implementation to something that *might* throw. Adding `noexcept` is a one way street, safe to add (if it's correct) but unsafe to remove. You have to be sure that the function, intrinsically, could never throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be careful with `noexcept` in general.  Unless the compiler can prove that the function really won't throw any exceptions, then it must insert a dynamic handler to terminate your program in case of an exception.  Thus it won't necessarily lead to the optimizations you're hoping for.  In any case, adding it to `AddRef`, `Release`, and `QueryInterface` should be safe.

**Edit**

For example, consider the following code:

```
extern int Foo();

int Bar() noexcept
{
    return Foo();
}
```

This is what Clang 7.0 generates on O3:

```
Bar():                                # @Bar()
    push    rax
    call    Foo()
    pop     rcx
    ret
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    __clang_call_terminate
__clang_call_terminate:                 # @__clang_call_terminate
    push    rax
    call    __cxa_begin_catch
    call    std::terminate()
```

If you delete the `noexcept`, you get this instead:

```
Bar():                                # @Bar()
    jmp     Foo()                 # TAILCALL
```

In this example, the primary effect is just to bloat the image a little bit, but notice that the call to `Foo` also became a little less efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert a dynamic handler"? How does it affect performance?

Comment: It's a small bit of code to catch exceptions and call `std::terminate`.  It's rarely an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend adding noexcept wherever you can.

If you add it to a location and crash because of it, you've just learned that you can't use it there along with the reason why.

Comment: RCA of the escalation: Engineers were learning that they could not use noexcept on this business critical function.